# JPQL Querying Bit Flags

Tags: jpql

I Have in my msql table column of type Long, this column represent bit falgs.

I need to select objects for which all of several flags are set :
columnValue & flags = columnValue

I try :

```
javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT u FROM Userattributes u WHERE  u.myValueFlags & mask :=  mask");
q.setParameter("mask", mask);
```

But i have a syntax error :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred
>   while creating a query in EntityManager:  Exception Description:
>   Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT u FROM Userattributes u WHERE
>   u.userattributesPK.attributeID =:attributeId and u.myValueFlags & mask
>   :=  mask], line 1, column 103: unexpected token [mask]. Internal
>   Exception: NoViableAltException(78!=[652:1:
>   simpleConditionalExpressionRemainder[Object left] returns [Object
>   node] : (n= comparisonExpression[left] | (n1= NOT )? n=
>   conditionWithNotExpression[(n1!=null), left] | IS (n2= NOT )? n=
>   isExpression[(n2!=null), left] );])
>           at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1328)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:425)

Answer (score 3):

That cannot be done because JPQL does not have support for bitwise operations.